# How to show numbers correctly in wpf data binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, floating-point, format

i am using wpf and my problem is in showing float numbers. in general when i bind my data(float number) to a datagrid column it even shows two zero after my rounded number (3.00) but i want to show this two zero just if my value is not rounded. how to solve this problem?

3 -> 3 not 3.00

3.62 -> 3.62

Answer (score 8, accepted):

StringFormat is what you need.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyFloat, StringFormat='0:0.##'}" />
```

If this is not work, try '{0:0.##}'

Comment: Both variants don't work. Write it like this: `StringFormat='{}{0:0.##}'` . . . . . note: The leading `{}` is only needed if `{` is the first char of the StringFormat. If you have text in front of the value, you don't need the `{}` (e.g. `StringFormat='myValue: {0:0.##}'`).